# Replace values in one column based on the value of another column using a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have shrunk down my dictionary and data frame. If it was only two entries, I know I can use if-then statements.

My dictionary is as follows:

`region_rename = {"Gambia": "Sub-Saharan Africa", "North Macedonia": "Central and Eastern Europe"}`

My data frame, called data_2019, look like this:

`**Country**                **Region**                   **GDP**`
`Gambia                       NaN                          200`  
`North Macedonia              NaN                          300`  
`USA                          North America                400`

The output should be this:
`**Country**                **Region**                          **GDP**`
`Gambia                       Sub-Saharan Africa                  100`  
`North Macedonia              Central and Eastern Europe          200`  
`USA                          North America                       300`

I have tried this snippet of code but got a boolean answer in return.

```
data_2019["Region"] =  
    [data_2019.loc[data_2019["Country or region"] == r, "Region"] == region_rename[r] for r in region_rename]
```

I have also tried this other line of code but it tells me that the output in ambiguous.

```
sample["Region"] = sample["Region"].apply([
    lambda r: region_rename[r] if sample["Region"] == r else "" for r in region_rename])
```

If I use this other line of code, it replaces all other countries with the correct regions with NaN since they aren't defined in the dictionary.

```
sample["Region"] = sample["Country or region"].map(region_rename)
```

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to do it using mask

```
# check if map exists, and when it does, do the mapping

sample["**Country**"] = sample["**Country**"].mask(sample["**Country**"].map(region_rename).notna(), 
                           sample["**Country**"].map(region_rename))
```

OR

```
# using loc

sampe.loc[sample["**Country**"].map(region_rename).notna(),
"**Region**"] = sample["**Country**"].map(region_rename)
```

```
    **Country**     **Region**                  **GDP**
0   Gambia          Sub-Saharan Africa          200
1   North Macedonia Central and Eastern Europe  300
2   USA             North America               400
```

Comment: I've tried both suggestions and neither works. I have update my question to give more context about other additional columns in the data frame.

The output of the first solution tells me to specify axis=0 or 1 and then tells me the columns needs to the same length as the key.

The second suggested solution has typos I think. I also fixed my question, changing `sample` to `data_2019` in my third attempt of code.

Comment: I found a solution through brute force. I first find all NaN values and name this data frame `nulls`. Then I fill in those NaN values using the dictionary. Finally, I use this: `final = data_2019.fillna(nulls)`.

Comment: with more specifics added and made it reproducible in the question,  I updated the solution  @user20443632